# Form to input to sql database not working

Tags: php, html, sql, database

I am trying to make a website that will take data from a html form and add it to a sql database

post.html:

```
<form action="send_post.php" method="post">
<h3>ID:</h3>
<input type="text" name="id">
<h3>Name:</h3>
<input type="text" name="name">
<h3>Surname:</h3>
<input type="text" name="surname">
<input type="submit">
```

send_post.php

```
<?php  
$connect = mysqli_connect("myhost","myusername","mypassword","myDB");
mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO test_table (id, name, surname)
VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[surname]')"
?>
```

I have hosted it [here](http://samrobbins.125mb.com/post.html)

However when I try it says that there is a unexpected semicolon in a line where there is not a semi colon. How do I fix this?

Comment: It says the error is on line 7, however you only posted 5 lines of code?

Comment: Now go and change your passwords

Comment: Check once again on what line, in what file and what the **exact** error. And post relevant code.

Comment: I had some comments in which I deleted, I have updated it, it now says line 5

Comment: `mysqli_query` should have closing `)`

Comment: i think you're missing `);` at the end of `mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO test_table (id, name, surname)
VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[surname]')"`

Comment: The error is on the line that only has ?> in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Missing `);` Use this...

`mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO test_table (id, name, surname)
VALUES ('$_POST[id]', '$_POST[name]', '$_POST[surname]')");`